# Autocomplete for import keyword is ommiting file extension

Tags: webstorm

I am having a problem with WebStorm auto complete when using **import** keyword in JavaScript.
You can see an example here: https://i.gyazo.com/95adbf84c964663f715fc069ba1e1e8a.mp4

Basically when I auto complete following code:

```
import {loadLevel, loadSprite} from './loaders';
```

It doesn't add a file extension to loaders, which should look like this:

```
import {loadLevel, loadSprite} from './loaders.js';
```

I am using latest WebStorm version, I also tried to Invalidate cache and restarted IDE.
I am using JavaScript ES6 version in settings.
There are no other files called loaders with different extension anywhere else in my project.

If you need any more info, let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebStorm supports completing file name with extension (when using completion in the `from` part). To enable completing file name with extension, set registry key `commonjs.complete.required.filename.with.extension` to `true` :

- Open **Help | Find Action...** dialog
- Type `Registry`, find **Registry** item in dropdown list and press `Enter`
- Find `commonjs.complete.required.filename.with.extension` there, tick the checkbox

But this hidden option doesn't affect auto-imports, so, when auto-creating import statement from reference, extension won't be added - [WEB-28741](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28741)

Comment: I made those changes and I am trying to autocomplete at "from" keyword, nothing happens.  
Do I need to use shift + space? ctrl + space? I tried them all, it either doesn't work or open up a list with other file names etc.  

I restarted WebStorm too.

Comment: you need using `Ctrl+space` and choose desired file from the completion  list

Comment: It works, it is far from what I expected and it's probably faster to just type out the name, but if it's able to handle nested folders then it would be nice.  Thanks